# app runs properly on emulator but improperly on real device

Tags: android, xml, apk

What my app should do: 
Open a Register Activity the first time a user opens the app. 
Open a LogIn Activity the 2nd Time a user opens the app.

In the emulator this works fine. On a real device the Register Activity is never opened an the LogIn Activity opens. Why does my app behave differently on a real device vs the emulator?

I have an activity I created to control which activity is launched:

```
public class Launcher extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (UserDB.COL_PWRD.isEmpty()||(UserDB.COL_PWRD == null)||(UserDB.COL_PWRD.equals(null))) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Launcher.this, Register.class));
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(Launcher.this, LogInActivity.class));
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

I have the Launcher activity set to MAIN in my manifest:

```
      ///////////FIND INFO ACTIVITY
        <activity
            android:name=".FindInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Launcher" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      //////////LOG IN ACTIVITY
        <activity
            android:name=".LogInActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Launcher" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      //////////REGISTER ACTIVITY
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Launcher" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      //////////LAUNCHER ACTIVITY
        <activity
            android:name=".Launcher"
            android:label="PwdKpr" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Launcher" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

If you need me to post any other part of my code just ask.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your application on a device to see what state your variables are in? My guess is that while developing you created and set certain values in your database that are not being initialized the way you expect with a fresh install.

Comment: @Tanis.7x I've tried new devices in the emulator as well as wiping the data from the emulator.. is that not the same? I've also deleted all the databases in the device manager.

Comment: That should emulate a fresh install. I still recommend stepping through your code and ensuring that all values are what you expect.

Comment: 2 months later and this problem still is not solved. :(